# interaction between Queue and pool of Threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

I am creating a C++ application that receives data from an external provider. The amount of data per second can be very big. I have thought of using a thread that pushes the data into a Queue. then a pool of threads will fetch data from that Queue.

my questions are:

1. is this a good way to deal with this problem?
2. if not what is the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: It's well known as the producer/consumer pattern and an ubiquitous solution.

Comment: am thking of using stl::Queue object. are there any other type of Queues that optimise the use of memory ....Also gor the Thread pool are there any Known ones?

Comment: You can use `std::queue` of course, additionally have a `std::mutex` to protect read/write operations, and a condition variable or semaphore, to notify threads from  the pool that data is available.

Comment: One alternative is to have one queue per thread and then cycle through the queues as data is read. This way each thread can block/wait for one or more elements on it's "input" queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- is this a good way to deal with this problem.

It's a well known pattern, and used in many applications.

You can use a `std:queue` to implement this. Just protect the read/write operations on it using a `std:mutex`. Also you should have a condition variable or semaphore, where the pooled threads are waiting, and be notified, when new data is available in the queue.